# Prove (or check) an expression is positive given constraints on variables?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, assumptions

I'm trying to figure out whether an expression is always positive given positive parameters. When the expression is complicated, I can't do this by eye. Is there any way to make *Mathematica* prove (that is, check) if `j` is positive for positive `c, d, k, ton, toff, V`?

```
j=-2 c d k toff ton - d^2 k toff ton - 2 c k toff^2 ton - 
 2 d k toff^2 ton - k toff^3 ton - 2 c d k ton^2 - d^2 k ton^2 - 
 4 c k toff ton^2 - 4 d k toff ton^2 - 3 k toff^2 ton^2 - 
 2 c k ton^3 - 2 d k ton^3 - 3 k toff ton^3 - 
 k ton^4 + (Sqrt[k] Sqrt[ton] (toff + ton) Sqrt[
    d + toff + 
     ton] (2 c + d + toff + 
      ton) \[Sqrt]((c + d) k ton (c + toff + ton) (d + toff + ton) + 
       4 c d ((d + toff + ton) (k toff + (toff + ton)^2) + 
          c (k toff + 
             d (toff + ton) + (toff + ton)^2)) V))/(2 Sqrt[(c + 
       d) (c + toff + ton)]) + (Sqrt[k] Sqrt[
    ton] (toff + ton) Sqrt[(c + d) (c + toff + ton)] Sqrt[
    d + toff + 
     ton] (k ton (d + toff + ton) (2 c + d + toff + ton) + 
      4 d ((d + toff + ton) (k toff + (toff + ton)^2) + 
         2 c (k toff + 
            d (toff + ton) + (toff + ton)^2)) V))/(2 \[Sqrt]((c + 
          d) k ton (c + toff + ton) (d + toff + ton) + 
       4 c d ((d + toff + ton) (k toff + (toff + ton)^2) + 
          c (k toff + d (toff + ton) + (toff + ton)^2)) V))
```

I have many more expressions like this. I have tried putting in random values of the parameters and I do (so far) always get positive values. But I'd prefer something more convincing than a Monte Carlo argument for this (and other) complicated expressions being positive for any positive inputs. Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's define:

```
f[c_, d_, k_, toff_, ton_, V_] := "the expression equal to j"
```

Instead of using `toff`, `ton` and `V` I'll use `x, y, z`. Moreover we define:

```
assumptions = c > 0 && d > 0 && k > 0 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0;
```

In case of simpler functions we would try to do something like this:

```
Reduce[ f[c, d, k, x, y, z] > 0 && assumptions, {c, d, k, x, y, z}]
```

Although I favor exact symbolic results it would be quite inefficient to prove symbolically that `f[c, d, k, x, y, z]` is positive when its arguments are restricted by `assumptions`. In fact much faster way would harness certain numerical functions. Since we would like to prove that  `f[c, d, k, x, y, z]` is positive there should be an extremal value of the function given positive arguments.
Therefore we can exploit [**NMinimize**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NMinimize.html?q=NMinimize&lang=en) with appropriate constraints, it's the fastest way for such an involved expression.

```
NMinimize[{ f[c, d, k, x, y, z], assumptions}, {c, d, k, x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> {5.05906*10^-12, {c -> 2.52667, d -> 14.2925, k -> 0.273797,
>                   x -> 5.88427, y -> 6.14607, z -> 0.          }}
> ```

We've found that the minimum is a positive number for real numbers constrained by `assumptions`. 
Thus we are ensured that `f[c, d, k, x, y, z] > 0` for all positive arguments. 
Moreover the result is returned in less than a half of second while with `Reduce` it would take at least a few minutes.

Comment: Another idea to avoid assumptions: `NMinimize[j /. (Thread[# -> #^2]), #] &@Variables[j]` replaces all variables by their squares first.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for your help. Two questions: 1. if we assumed z>0, why is it returning v=0? Shouldn't that be explicitly prohibited? 2. I'm getting not quite the same result: {-9.09495*10^-12, {c -> 2.52665, d -> 14.2924, k -> 0.274061, 
  x -> 5.88441, y -> 6.14624, z -> 0.}} The parameters are the same, but the function value is different (and negative). It's also extraordinarily small, so do we chalk this up to round-off error? Thanks for your time!

Comment: @vector07 `NMinimize` yields numerical approximations so `z -> 0.` means that the minimum is at `0` (within the default precission) however for `z > 0` the value of `f` should be greater. If you find some inconsistency of the result you should provide your input to the original question editing it. I suppose you've done some mistake with your input. I checked my result with another functions an it was always positive.

Comment: Think it's just roundoff error. Thanks.