# Why does Maximize return a wrong answer?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to find the maximum of the following function, but get a wrong result.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Clear[x, y, xx, yy]
peaks[x_, y_] := 
  3*(1 - x)^2.*Exp[-(x^2) - (y + 1)^2] - 
   10*(x/5 - x^3 - y^5) Exp[-x^2 - y^2] - 1/3 Exp[-(x + 1)^2 - y^2];
N[Maximize[peaks[xx, yy], {xx, yy}]]
NMaximize[{peaks[x, y], x >= -2, x <= 2, y >= -2, y <= 3}, {x, y}]
peaks[0, 2]
peaks[1.28568, -0.00484756]
```

When you look at these graphs, you realize that the results are strange:

```
peaks[x_, y_] := 3*(1 - x)^2*Exp[-(x^2) - (y + 1)^2] - 
                 10*(x/5 - x^3 - y^5) Exp[-x^2 - y^2] - 1/3 Exp[-(x + 1)^2 - y^2];
Plot3D[peaks[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 3}, 
    ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
    AxesLabel -> Automatic]
ContourPlot[peaks[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 3},  
    ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
    ContourLines -> False,  
    Contours -> 25]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: More on the related problems you'll find examining these two  posts: [Prove (or check) an expression is positive given constraints on variables?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47185/prove-or-check-an-expression-is-positive-given-constraints-on-variables/47187#47187) and  about the `Maximize` issue: [How do I determine the maximum value for a polynomial, given a range of x values?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37225/how-do-i-determine-the-maximum-value-for-a-polynomial-given-a-range-of-x-values/37227#37227)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `FindMaximum`:

```
FindMaximum[peaks[xx, yy], {xx, yy}]
```

> {8.106, {xx -> -0.009, yy -> 1.581}}

```
plot = Plot3D[peaks[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All];

point = Graphics3D[{PointSize@0.05, Point[{-0.009, 1.581, 8.106}]}];

Show[plot, point]
```

[image]

On the other hand, `Maximize` returns in this case the last local maximum it can find:

[image]

Comment: ok, but... Why maxime gives bad results?

Comment: When I dlouldn´t use Maximize?

Comment: @Mika Ike - If you have to use `NMaximize` you can go with Bob Hanlon's answer.

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation for `Maximize`: "If f and cons are linear or polynomial, `Maximize` will always find a global maximum."  and "If `Maximize` is given an expression containing approximate numbers, it automatically calls `NMaximize`."

From documentation for `NMaximize`: "If f and cons are linear, `NMaximize` can always find global maxima, over both real and integer values." and "Otherwise, `NMaximize` may sometimes find only a local maximum."

Your function is neither linear nor polynomial and you get just a local maximum.

```
Clear[x, y, xx, yy]
peaks[x_, y_] := 
  3*(1 - x)^2*Exp[-(x^2) - (y + 1)^2] - 
   10*(x/5 - x^3 - y^5) Exp[-x^2 - y^2] - 1/3 Exp[-(x + 1)^2 - y^2];
```

Try different methods for `NMaximize`

```
NMaximize[{peaks[x, y], -2 <= x <= 2, -2 <= y <= 3}, {x, y}, 
   Method -> #] & /@ {"NelderMead", "DifferentialEvolution", 
  "SimulatedAnnealing", "RandomSearch"}
```

> {{3.59249, {x -> 1.28568, y -> -0.00484756}}, {8.10621, {x -> -0.00931759, 
>      y -> 1.58137}}, {8.10621, {x -> -0.0093176, 
>      y -> 1.58137}}, {8.10621, {x -> -0.00931757, y -> 1.58137}}}

Answer (score 2):

Your function `peaks[x_, y_] := 3*(1 - x)^2.*Exp` has a decimal point after the `2`, which makes the `2` a `Real` and not an `Integer`. Remove it and `Maximize[peaks[xx, yy], {xx, yy}]` just returns the input, while 
`NMaximize[peaks[xx, yy], {xx, yy}]` gives `{3.59249, {xx -> 1.28568, yy -> -0.00484755}}`.

The function `peaks`is just to complex to allow a symbolic solution, I guess.

Added 19:52 CET

```
NMaximize[peaks[xx, yy], {xx, yy}, Method -> RandomSearch]`
```

gives

> ```
> {8.10621, {xx -> -0.00931759, yy -> 1.58137}}`
> ```

See the help file for other options. Finding a global maximum numerically can always be made to fail; just add a very sharp spike, say

```
1000*Exp[-((x - u)^2 + (y - v)^2)/2/w^2]
```

and let `w` get extremely small. No numeric algorithm can ever locate that spike.

Comment: I tried, but the results are a little strange. See the edited post