# Maximize vs FindMaximum

Tags: mathematical-optimization

This can be thought of as follow-up to [this question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50795/why-does-maximize-return-a-wrong-answer) The question is, simply, can anyone explain why both `Maximize[]` and `FindMaximum[]` (and their minimalist counterparts) exist. The documentation seems to draw no meaningful distinction between the two...

Comment: Some useful information can be found in Ruskeepää's  [Mathematica Navigator (3rd ed), pp. 741 ff.](http://math.bme.hu/~jtoth/Mma/Mathematica%20Navigator%202009%203rd%20Edition.pdf).

Answer (score 7):

[`FindMaximum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum.html) searches for a **local** maximum in `f`, starting from an automatically selected point.

```
max1 = FindMaximum[x Cos[x], x]

(*  {0.561096, {x -> 0.860334}}  *)
```

Specifying different starting values gives different results

```
max2 = FindMaximum[x Cos[x], {x, #}] & /@ {1, 6, 10}

(*  {{0.561096, {x -> 0.860334}}, {6.361, {x -> 6.4373}}, {12.6059, {x -> 
    12.6453}}}  *)
```

[`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html) searches for a **global** maximum. If `f` and `constraints` are linear or polynomial, `Maximize` will always find a global maximum.

```
Maximize[{x Cos[x], 0 < x < 15}, x] // N

(*  {12.6059, {x -> 12.6453}}  *)
```

To find all peaks in the interval

```
sol3 = ({x Cos[x], {"x" -> x}} /.
    NSolve[{
      D[x Cos[x], x] == 0,
      D[x Cos[x], {x, 2}] < 0,
      0 < x < 15}, x]) /. "x" :> x

(*  {{0.561096, {x -> 0.860334}}, {6.361, {x -> 6.4373}}, {12.6059, {x -> 
    12.6453}}}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize that `FindMaximum[]` did not even try to look for a global maximum...

Comment: To add, `NMaximize[]` **tries** to find a global maximum.